# Are empty loops okay to use?

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, command, actionevent

I'm working on a text based game with a GUI as the "console" for input and output. My objective is to, when the game asks for it, submit a command I have typed in a JTextArea to another method.

To do this I have come up with this idea: when `user.readLine()` is called, it loops until the GUI receives an action event. Detection of this event is accomplished by the flipping of a boolean called `commanded`, toggled in the actionevent's method. `readLine()` then breaks the loop at this point and returns the text that was just entered, then flips the boolean back. Interestingly enough, this only works if I add a     `System.out.println();` or a `Thread.sleep(1);` before flipping the boolean back...

The `readLine()` method involves a lot of looping with no code between the braces, as it waits for the Action Event. Is it wrong to think of this as a "short circuit" and something to be avoided? Code is below. Thanks!

CommandInput.java:

```
public void waitForCommand() {
    try {
        processCommand(Parasite.user.readLine().toLowerCase());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

UI.java (initialized as Parasite.user):

```
boolean commanded= false;
String command = "";

public final String readLine()
{
    while(commanded == false)
    {
       System.err.print(command);
    }
    System.out.println("Submitting Command");
    commanded = false;
    return command;       
}

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    commanded=true;
    command=jTextField1.getText();
    System.err.println(jTextField1.getText());  
    jTextField1.setText("");

}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s bad. Try implementing something event-based instead.

Comment: When you have a loop that is constantly spinning, you are basically burning up one CPU core just for waiting. Also, there is no bound on how long it will take for the change in the variable to be detected by the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

The short circuit thing:
Loops that don't do much in words of other than looping like this:

```
while(true) {}
```

are not very CPU friendly, much better would be soemthing like this:

```
while(true) {
    Thread.yield();
}
```

This says the CPU, that this thread can be stopped right now, so other threads can run now, it gets moved down in the Thread queue. You don't loose that much of precision doing this, but it prevents you from using all of your cpu. (look here for more information: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) )

So in your case:

```
while(commanded == false)
{
   System.err.print(command);
    Thread.yield();
}
```

Comment: The articles I've read about this say that Thread.yield() usually shouldn't be used because it doesn't work as it should most of the time. What should I look for in profiling results to make sure it is working the way it should be?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) article on how to use event driven programming to solve your problem.  In short, your approach is inefficient and does not scale well

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going to assume that any approach of event-driven programming would be better than what I have right now, so I think I'll need to research about other methods as well to find the best one for my project.